# Spring Boot Application not authenticating once in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-sdk

I have a REST API Spring Boot application for AWS that is being developed. It has been developed on a local machine and through that local machine, we have been able to pull down live AWS data even through it was on a local machine and the URL was localhost. We have finished most of development and are ready to move it up to the cloud. However, now that we created a JAR, hosted it on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and call the API URL, AWS now gives us a 500 Access Denied Error.

Currently, our local application was being authenticated through variables in the application.properties file of our project. Those seem to not apply in the cloud environment. We also tried setting the environment variables in the Elastic Beanstalk to the same values that we have in our application.properties but that still returns a 500 error.

Here is our exact returned error from AWS

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-07-02T20:23:31.400+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Access Denied (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 66CA2FE6CEE7A5D4)",
    "path": "/api/s3/buckets/list"
}
```

And here is the application.properties file where I placed the security keys

```
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you instantiate the credentials into your AWS client locally. It needs to be modified for use in the AWS environment.

Comment: I meant where in your application you are creating an S3 client, sorry! Should be something like this where you create an S3 client using default credentials: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: @Compass I don't instantiate the credentials anywhere except for placing them in the application.properties file. My calls to AWS clients are simply S3Client.builder().region(REGION_VAR).build() and it just works that way

Comment: @Compass I should also mention that my credentials are also loaded in the`~/.aws/credentials` file so they could be pulling from there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Elastic Beanstalk might not have read/write role through which it can access S3. You won't need credentials when running in AWS, everything depends on roles (permissions)

Comment: That was correct - There was an Elastic beanstalk role that was created when I loaded the web app on there but I didn't give that role anything other than access to itself. When I gave it S3FullAccess then it was able to pull and retrieve data.